# Flush output of `tail -f` into a file?

Tags: tail

I have an app which dumps a lot of log messages. I want to catch a middle of that log, which happens as a reaction to an event.

Tried this:

```
tmpfile=`mktemp`
tail -n1 -f appA_log_file.txt >> $tmpfile  &
appB_sends_events_to_appA
sleep 1
pkill tail
cat $tmpfile
rm $tmpfile
```

This script works. But I am concerned about `sleep 1`. It is necessary for the `tail` to notice the changes in the huge log and write it down to the temp file. Without it, I see only one line - right before the execution of `appB`.

Is there a way to force `tail` to flush whatever it has in buffers or not read yet and exit without `pkill`?

Tried using `stdbuf`:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 tail -n1 -f appA_log_file.txt >> $tmpfile  &
```

but it still requires a `sleep` before `pkill`.

Or is there a better approach to the whole problem?

Comment: `tail -n1 -f -s 0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the key `-s0` for `tail` solved the problem.

As alternative, tried to do

```
echo '-start' >> appA_log_file.txt
appB_sends_events_to_appA
echo '-end' >> appA_log_file.txt
sed '/-start/,/-end/p' appA_log_file.txt
```

But failed, due to fact that `appA` is holding its log in exclusive mode and I just could not insert markers into the file.

But `tail -s0 -f` works fine.